# Amended return (dead or alive): What address or addresses to use for various forms?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, amended-tax-return

An amended return multiple forms, most of which require an address. But if the address has changed since the original return, then what address do you enter on each form?

For example, the amended return I am preparing requires an address for the following:

- 1040X showing a summary of the amended return
- Corrected 1040 and supporting schedules (including Schedule C)
- 1310 to claim refunds

It makes sense for the 1040X and the 1310 to have the current address (i.e., the address for the personal representative), but what about the corrected 1040 and schedules which were originally filed with a different address. Should all of those also have the current address?

That would seem logical because the IRS uses the last known address to send communications. But (play music here and envision Tina Turner) "What's logic got to do with it?"

Tried searching at the IRS site for the answer to this specific question, but was not successful.

Another way of restating the question might be this: For an amended return, do you always show the same current address on all forms?

Comment: IMO, this is a call the IRS type question. They're likely to be your most direct route to the fastest correct answer.

Comment: Nada. The phone waits are awful, and the answers you get from IRS personnel are inconsistent. I have more faith in answers from people who have "been there, done that."